# How to create a pivot tablefor this problem:

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is my original table:

[Original table](https://i.postimg.cc/RZpwPc6M/original-T.jpg)

And I would like it to be as:

```
CityID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7
_____________________________________
1024    0800 0900 and so on...
```

Here is my code, but I get a syntax error near FOR.

```
select * from
(select SIDURI as CityID, DAY as ArrivalDay, T_FROM as TimeArrival
from RNFIL488)  as timingTable
pivot(
timing.SIDURI as CityID
timingTable.T_FROM as TimeArrival
for timing.DAY as ArrivalDay in (
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5],
[6],
[7]
)
) as pivot_table
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CityID ORDER BY ArrivalDay) rn
    FROM RNFIL488
)

SELECT
    CityID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [2],
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [3],
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [4],
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [5],
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [6],
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN TimeArrival END) AS [7]
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    CityID;
```

This assumes that your original source table would always have 7 arrival days per city.  If not, then we might have to use a calendar table to bring in the missing data.  Also, I am avoiding the `PIVOT` operator, because often the above approach performs better (and I also find it much easier to read).

Comment: For each city, there are 7 rows (=days). If there is no arrival to the city on day 7, TimeArrival will be 00000

Comment: @Chaim Please add sample data directly to your question which explains your comment above.

Comment: I added a link to an image. My organization limit my access to a better images store websites

Comment: How can I put this code inside another query? I need it to be as a table for join. I tried to put it in ( ), but I get an error

Comment: You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend if you don't have a lot data then you can truncate the table and re-fill table. And don't forget your id column should be unique and use `auto_increment` on id.

Comment: I consider this option

Comment: `auto_increment` is `identity` in SQL Server.

Comment: @daleK maybe CityId is identity